# Rails: Allow users to only view or edit their own content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan, rolify

I'm using `devise`, and up to now I have only added the `devise` controllers along with the views for three users (user1, user2, admin). I don't have any `before_action :authenticate_user!` in any controller. Basically [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models) is what I have done thus far.
Thus, currently all registered users can login and view/edit all content. At this point I would like to restrict each user to view or edit only his content.

This is basically what I'm after: The admin will have access to all of the app. User1 will have access to `get 'books/search' => 'books#search', as: 'search_books'` and thus `root 'books#search'`. And User2 would be able to add/delete/edit a book via the `resources :books and also view his current account.

Not sure what access I should give the `resources :plans, resources :accounts, resources :transactions`. Plans are in order to purchase plans, along with the transactions, and accounts belong to user2. You can see the associations below.

I did a bit of research on this and found a couple of `gems`, `CanCan`, `rolify` which add roles to users.

Is there a another way I can implement the roles with `devise`?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'books#search'

  get 'books/search' => 'books#search', as: 'search_books'
  get "/cancel_subscription", to: "accounts#cancel_subscription", as: "cancel_subscription"

  devise_for :admins, controllers: {registrations: 'admins/registrations', sessions: 'admins/sessions'}, :class_name => 'Admin' do
    get "admins/dashboard"=> "admins/sessions#dashboard", :as => "admin_dashboard"
  end

  devise_for :users1, controllers: {registrations: 'users1/registrations', sessions: 'users2/sessions'}
 devise_for :users2, controllers: {registrations: 'users2/registrations', sessions: 'users2/sessions'}

 resources :books do
  resources :comments
 end
 resources :categories
 resources :plans
 resources :accounts
 resources :transactions, only: [:new, :index, :create]
 end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user1
end

class Books < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

class User1 < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :comments
end

class User2 < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :account, autosave: true
  has_many :books

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
end

class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Comment: You sound confused about what you're trying to achieve here.... If all you want to do is add the ability to mark users as `admin`, then why not just add a `is_admin` boolean column to the `users` table? If you are having issues setting up the controller/permitter logic, then please **show us your code** so that we can diagnose the problem.

Comment: You should use pundit gem. => https://github.com/elabs/pundit <= it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you implemented multi-user support? How are users and their content are connected, how are the associations defined?

Comment: Thanks for the replies @Tom Lord, I have updated the question with more info and details. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the replies @ spickermann, I have updated the question with more info and details. I hope it helps!

Comment: OK, now I'm really confused... Why is there a **model** for `user1` and `user2`?? (And none for `admin`?) Do you expect your application to have **lots** of users, with three different roles/permission levels (in which case, I'd suggest using more descriptive names than `user1` and `user2`!)? Or, do you want to have exactly three users in the whole system? (In which case, why do you have `registrations`?) ... Or, and I suspect this is the case, do you want to have **many** users categorised simply as **admins / non-admins**?

Comment: Basically, can you please clarify what the user model is supposed to look like - because I highly suspect you've taken a wrong turn here, and gotten mixed up with your classes.

Comment: @Tom Lord... Actually I do have an admin model, I just forgot to add it. Yes I do expect my application to have lots of users and thats why I wanted to split the models/controllers/views. I want three users with different types of roles/permissions on my app, admin, seller, viewer. The admin is the admin, the seller sells stuff and the viewer just views the uploaded stuff. Sorry if I confused you!!

Comment: If the role is a `Seller` and a `Viewer`, then call it something meaningful like that!! Not `User1` and `User2`! :D .... Your design is also dependant on whether a seller can also be a viewer.

Comment: If each user can simply be defined by their class, then you could add a bunch of `pundit` policies with rules like: `user.is_a?(Admin) || user.is_a?(Seller)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to check for the type of class of the current with

`if current_user.class.eql?(class_name_of_user)
   #perform some action
 end`

You can refine it by making this a private method in your controller and calling it through a before_action callback.